# Why differs gl_FragCoord.z from ((pos.z / pos.w) + 1.0) * 0.5?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, opengl-es

Does anyone know why 'depth' (vertShader) differs from 'gl_FragCoord.z' (rendered from opengl)? Especially with decreasing z the difference becomes higher. Is it possible that 'depth' is at higher z values more precise?

```
.vsh
out float depth;
void main (void) {
    vec4 pos = mvpMatrix * vertex;
    depth = ((pos.z / pos.w) + 1.0) * 0.5;
    gl_Position = pos;
}

.fsh
in float depth;
void main(void) {
    gl_FragDepth = depth;// or gl_FragCoord.z;
}
```

Comment: Is there any difference between `((pos.z / pos.w) + 1.0) * 0.5;` and `(pos.z / pos.w) * 0.5 + 0.5;` at low z values? Could it be a float precision issue?

Comment: It's the same, unfortunately no difference. Maybe depth should be calculated in the fragShader, because of interpolation?

Comment: Do you call `glDepthRange*` or `glClipControl`? Do you use the default frame buffer?

Comment: I don't call glDepthRange* or glClipControl. yes I'm using the default framebuffer, mainly for opengl es. but it also deviates on win10.

Comment: It seems a float precision issue, specially if you set the depth buffer as of type 24 bits (not all drivers accept a 32 bit depth buffer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your approach, with the main points are:

1. `gl_FragCoord.z` is hyperbolically distorted window space z value. However, the hyperoblical `z/w` value for each vertex is just *linearily* interpolated in screen space for each framgent. But when you use a varying `out float depth = (pos.z / pos.w)`, the GL will do a perspective-corrected interpolation which is non-linear. You could fix this by using `flat out float depth`.
2. `(pos.z/pos.w)` doesn't even make sense. Think about it: if the point lies in a plane where the camera is, you'll get `pos.w=0`, and no valid result. `gl_FragCoord.z` does not have this issue because the clipping is done before the divide, and it will do the divide for a new vertex which lies on the near plane, and which you'll never going to see (there's no vertex shader invocation for that).

   The issue is also present when points lie behind the camera, they will end up mirrored in front of the camera. If you have a primitive where vertices lie on both sides of the camera, you will get complete bullshit as your interpolated `depth` value, no matter which interpolation method you chose.

Comment: Also remember most depth buffers are 24-bit unorm values, so cannot represent every value which a 32-bit float in a shader can represent.

Comment: @solidpixel: that's tru, but irrelevant. neither a user-defined varying nor `gl_FragCoord.z` comes from the depth buffer.